# How to Make the Inventory Uneditable like Shops?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am quite new to Spigot plugin development. I was trying to create a shop plugin which most of the Minecraft servers have.

```java
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

public class Commands implements CommandExecutor {


    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender commandSender, Command command, String s, String[] strings) {

        Player player = (Player) commandSender;
        if( commandSender instanceof Player)
        {
            if(command.getName().equals("shop"))
            {
                Inventory shop = Bukkit.createInventory(player,27,"Shop");


                ItemStack unused = new ItemStack(Material.LIGHT_GRAY_STAINED_GLASS_PANE , 1);

                ItemStack Wood = new ItemStack(Material.OAK_LOG , 1);
                ItemStack Food = new ItemStack(Material.PORKCHOP , 1);
                ItemStack Stone = new ItemStack(Material.STONE , 1);
                ItemStack Tools = new ItemStack(Material.IRON_PICKAXE , 1);
                ItemStack Redstone = new ItemStack(Material.REDSTONE_BLOCK , 1);

                shop.setItem(11,Redstone);
                shop.setItem(12,Wood);
                shop.setItem(13,Stone);
                shop.setItem(14,Food);
                shop.setItem(15,Tools);

                for(int i = 0; i < 27;i++)
                {
                    if((i >= 0 && i<=10) || (i >=16 && i<=26))
                    {
                        shop.setItem(i,unused);
                    }
                }

                player.openInventory(shop);

            }

        }
        else
        {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "Only a Player can Execute the Command.");
        }

        return true;
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onInventoryShopClick(InventoryClickEvent e)
    {
        
    }
}
```

I'm not able to get a solution to make the shop object of class Inventory uneditable, which is a local variable in function `onCommand()`. I want it so that if a player clicks on an object in the inventory, `event.setCancelled(true)` happens.

I am sorry if this is a stupid question but I only know how to manipulate events using the `InventoryClickEvent` in a separate function.

Comment: In your `onInventoryShopClick` check if the Inventory's title is equal to  your shops title and then cancel the event.

Answer (score 2):

Use `InventoryClickEvent e` to check if the inventory you are trying to control is the one the player clicked, then just run `e.setCancelled(true);`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the answer above, you can use the `InventoryClickEvent` event to check for inventory clicks, then use `e.setCancelled(true)` to cancel the event.

However, if you still want to be able to manipulate your normal inventory, check the inventory you are clicking on if it's the shop inventory and cancel the event:

```
public void onInventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent e) {
    if (e.getClickedInventory().getTitle().equals("shop")) {
        e.setCancelled(true);
    }
}
```